# Push Segue works but changing to Show does not

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have the following sequence

```
ContainerVC --> Nav --> TVC1 --> TVC2 --> VC1
```

All using storyboard for the connections and `performSegueWithIdentifier` in the code.

The flow has worked in the past but I am trying to update to the size classes and Autolayout since push is on the way out. During this change over I ran into multiple issues so I started from scratch to simplify the matter and I have this one issue that I just cannot for the life of me figure out but at the same time I think it is an error on my part.

The first show segue from TV1 to TV2 works as expected.
The second show segue is not working.
If I change that second segue to push my VC1 comes up as I expect.
Then I change it to show and it does not.

I can see the `performSegueWithIdentifier` being called. This is the same that is called when I have it set to push.
The reuse identifiers are set. I deleted them. Re-entered them. Copy pasted to them but nothing I have done will allow the Show version of the segue to work.

Since push still functions there must be something new that Show requires that I have left out.

If needed I can post the code later when I have access to it.

Any ideas? It's just got to be something simple that I am forgetting.

Comment: This will be much easier to figure out once you post the code. Also, is your app for iPad, iPhone, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue with my application, I believe its a bug with Xcode. Try deleting the view controllers with the issue then get back to me. You would have to delete the view controller and hook everything up once more again.

Comment: Thanks for advice of deleting the VC and reconnecting. I started from scratch instead but doing so has some how solved the issue. If I ever figure out what exactly I did wrong I will update this posting with the details. Otherwise you may be correct in that this is an Xcode bug.